# SQL to find string in select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I have a select statement like this:

```
SELECT ColumnA,
CASE ColumnB = 'England' THEN ...
```

In the part after the THEN statement, i want to take the numbers from ColumnC,

e.g. ColumnC value = ABC 123 DEF, and i need the '123' part.

Does anyone know the sql code i can use to do this within the select when the '123' will always be in between the only 2 spaces in the string? (MS SQL)

Comment: A hint about which RDBMS you are using would be quite helpful. Ahem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main key is that you need to use `ColumnC LIKE '% % %'` so that it does not fail when the data does not contain two spaces.

If your numbers are going to be less than 20-char long, you can use this

```
SELECT ColumnA,
CASE WHEN ColumnB = 'England' AND ColumnC LIKE '% % %' THEN
   RTRIM(LEFT(REPLACE(STUFF(columnc, 1, PatIndex('% %', columnc), ''), ' ', REPLICATE(' ', 20)),20))
ELSE ....
```

Or you can use this

```
SELECT ColumnA,
CASE WHEN ColumnB = 'England' AND ColumnC LIKE '% % %' THEN
    SUBSTRING(
        SUBSTRING(
            ColumnC,
            1,
            CHARINDEX(' ',ColumnC,CHARINDEX(' ', ColumnC)+1)-1),
        1+CHARINDEX(' ', ColumnC),
        LEN(ColumnC))
ELSE ....
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING`:

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE(ColumnC varchar(100))
INSERT @Test 
VALUES ('ABC 123 DEF')

SELECT SUBSTRING(ColumnC,
          CHARINDEX(' ', ColumnC) + 1, -- first space
          CHARINDEX(' ', ColumnC, CHARINDEX(' ', ColumnC) + 1)
             - CHARINDEX(' ', ColumnC)) -- length from first to second space 
FROM @Test
```

This works as expected for the sample string provided.

Comment: This has an upvote but I cant get it to work on mine... Hmm still playing with it!

Comment: How are you getting charindex of second space? Can you explain?

Comment: @sachin - By passing in the optional 3rd parameter that gives a start location to search.  I pass in the location of the previous space + 1.

Comment: Aaah... just missed out on that due to lot of charIndexes.. ;). Thanks for explaining the same. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( ColumnC , ' ', 2 ),' ',-1)
```

Comment: Is there an equivilent to SUBSTRING_INDEX for MS SQL??